# VPN vs real IP address

Tags: vpn, ip, nmap

Is it more secure to use a VPN that has open ports?

```
22/tcp open ssh 
53/tcp open domain 
80/tcp open http 
110/tcp open pop3 
443/tcp open https 
500/tcp open isakmp 
1723/tcp open pptp 
4567/tcp open tram 
8888/tcp open sun-answerbook
```

Or use the IP assigned by my ISP which has mostly filtered ports?

```
21/tcp    filtered ftp
53/tcp    open     domain
80/tcp    filtered http
548/tcp   open     afp
1036/tcp  filtered nsstp
3333/tcp  open     dec-notes
20005/tcp open     btx
```

In other words, if you are a hacker or pentester, would it be easier for you to gain root access to my machine with my vanilla IP or with my VPN IP?

Comment: Your question is quite unclear. Use for what? What does closed/filtered ports mean and what Open ports does your VPN have and why?

Comment: Basically I am saying that an "nmap ip" will result in more open ports for my VPN then for my standard IP address.

Comment: How would you possibly connect to a VPN service with all the externally facing means of communication either filtered or closed?

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: Basically, to establish a connection to a remote server (such as a VPN server), you need to connect to an open port on that remote server. (In practice, this might be a little bit more complicated but let's forget about that now.) How do you expect a VPN server to lack any open port then? You wouldn't be able to connect to it this way.

Comment: @CodyRutscher you assume that all those ports connect back to your machine

Comment: Maybe what he is saying is that, when connected through VPN, he goes to a site like "what's my ip" he sees IP address = "X." When not connected to VPN he goes to "whatsmyip" and sees IP address = "Y." Then when he runs nmap on X he sees ssh open and a bunch of crap, but when he runs nmap on Y he sees nothing open.

Comment: @hft yes, that's what he does, but this revelation doesn't clarify the question.

Comment: All those ports in theory might be just a stealthy VPN tunnel masquerade after all. At least, ports 22, 53, 80, and 443 are used for that purpose rather frequently.

Comment: I basically want to create a machine that is unhackable without social engineering. I figure that a system with closed and filtered ports and VPN is close to impossible to access without some form of social engineering or software vulnerability.

Comment: @CodyRutscher once again, there's not enough information in the question to responsibly guide you. A low-quality VPN service might be a much more serious threat for your privacy than your good ol' ISP line, but it's hard to tell the quality of this one looking at the open port list only.

Comment: Is it appropriate for me to ask for some guidance here? So you would recommend sticking with my default ISP line?

Comment: Personally, I'd recommend to read *"Computer Networks"* by Andrew S. Tanenbaum first.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you're confusing a bunch of points together. Most people would consider *"privacy"* to be equivalent to *"anonymity"*, ie whether or not your traffic can be traced back to your IP address. By and large, what services are being offered by a VPN company (and therefore what ports they have open) have no impact on whether I can trace traffic back to you through the VPN. How many customer service phone numbers my bank has is largely irrelevant to someone trying to trace my money transfers.

If your goal is privacy (ie hiding your IP address), then, umm, don't use your IP address.

---

**Let's back up and talk about your threat model**

In comments you say *"I basically want to create a machine that is unhackable without social engineering"* which is an almost completely separate goal from privacy / anonymity. It's also a much larger goal.

I think the first step in designing your security solution would be to decide what type and level of threat model you're trying to protect against. Some handy starter questions:

1. What do you want to protect? *(Data on your hard drive? Data you send over the network? Your computer against viruses? etc)*
2. Who do you want to protect it from? *(someone who finds your laptop unlocked? Amature hackers? Criminal hackers? Nation-state hackers?)*
3. How bad are the consequences if you fail?
4. How much time, effort, money, and changes to your internet usage behaviours are you willing to invest protecting it? *(Are you willing to stop carrying a cell phone? Only use live-boot Linux OSes? Give up facebook and youtube and any other website that breaks if you block javascript?)*

Bear in mind that the broader your threat model, the harder your job. It's very easy to say "... against all criminal hacking groups", and then you realize that even hiring a team of 30 security experts won't get you that.

To coin Mike's law of threat modelling:

> The universal threat model "Confidential even against my hardware manufacturer and the most sophisticated nation-state hackers" is basically meaningless.

Comment: The issue with hiding your IP address behind a VPN is that if someone breaks into that VPN server you're using, then you expose not only your IP address to them, but also *all* your communications. So you get much less privacy than if simply not hiding. So the right constraint here is: "your goal is privacy AND you're not a person of a particular interest, nobody's going to track you down personally". How those two conditions live together in a same sane threat model is interesting though.

Comment: @ximaera +1 I think there's an assumption baked in there that either the VPN provider is keeping sensitive logs, or that an attacker can get persistent monitoring tools into the VPN backend, right? So the quality of VPN service comes into play, right?

Comment: Exactly. More precisely, the second clause. My concern now is whether the author of the question does realise that issue or he's just checking some (sorry, senseless) formal conditions without any threat model in place.

Comment: Basically, I am looking for a model that protects me beyond my browser being hooked. I understand how easy it is to get socially engineered. I am more concerned with being the victim of a personal attack that involves zero social engineering.

Comment: @CodyRutscher AHA! A threat model! Editing that info into the question would actually turn it into a good question. If you can add details about their technical skills, whether they have physical access to your stuff, etc, that would be helpful.

Comment: Do you want me to edit that into the question, start a private chat, or answer it in a comment? And do you mind rating the question up if I make one of these changes?

Comment: @CodyRutscher Go ahead and re-vamp the question (or start a new one), then I'll see if I know enough to answer it (or someone else will)